# Replacement of setAttribute for IE6-7

Tags: javascript

I am using `elem.setAttribute()` method extensively though out my javascript. My script is working fine on all browsers except IE6 and 7. I know both of them doesn't support this method.

Is there any way to generalize or redefine `setAttibute()` so that it is recognized by all browsers, since my JavaScript is too long to be modified separately line by line.

Comment: It seems like IE7 supports this method: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#attributes

Comment: I recommend you to does not support ie 6 or 7 instead of fixing the ie weird behaviour on pretty much everything.

Comment: Though I myself would drop IE<8 support for as many time as possible, I do use `elem.setAttribute('required','');` a few minutes ago in my code and it seems IE6 knows it.

Comment: can you be more specific, is setAttribute not working for setting specific attribute...?

Comment: Use jQuery or similar library, would make your life a bit easier

Comment: Can you share the code which is not working in IE6-7